# Replacement CD delphi 2005 enterprise where to find?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2005

My company lost its cd for delphi and now we are trying to scour the net to find a copy we do have our cd key but not the actual cd does anyone have a copy or knows where I could purchase one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delphi 2005 is no longer supported by Embarcadero best option is to upgrade to 2007 and 2009

Comment: 2010 would cost to much as the upgrade to 2007 and 2009 only cost $399

Answer (score 10):

Why not ask [Embarcadero](http://support.embarcadero.com/forms/submitcase)?

Comment: Been there done that their support was able to find our registration info but they don't offer copies of 2005 only 2006 and upgrading is not an option due to the cost being over 2000 dollars.

Comment: @Michael Quiles: OK, then I see your frustration.

Answer (score 5):

You should look at [Registered User Download](http://cc.embarcadero.com/myreg) Page.

Even if you lost your product key, you can find it at https://members.embarcadero.com/Products.aspx

In both cases your product must have been registered before on your account.

If you lost the account used to register the product, then follow Andreas advice.

Comment: We did this but they don't have 2005 listed